# What is the proper placement of the feet on the pedals when viewed from the top?

Tags: pedals, bike-fit

When placing my feet on the pedals with the balls on it, the outer part doesn't fit the pedal anymore. If I moved the foot backwards, the pinky would not be on the pedal anymore.

I wonder if that is an issue or no problem at all.

Comment: You can get wider flat pedals, but they increase the risk of pedal strike while cornering.  This is bad.

Comment: What style riding ?  MTB is different to road.

Comment: Not a special "style". I just commute to work and use it to get from point A in the city to point B. Mostly 30 mins cycling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ultimate rule of bike fit, is that if it works for you (i.e., no pain or discomfort) then don't worry too about it too much. Once discomfort or pain becomes an issue then you will have to start to focus the cause.

In regards to generally accepted foot positions, right now most fitters are recommending having the axle of the pedal (the shaft that connects the pedal to the crank) between the 1st metatarsal (ball of foot) and the fifth metatarsal.

This puts the foot *forward* about 1 cm relative to lining up the ball of the foot with the pedal axle. Given your description of the problem, moving your foot forward would bring more of your foot onto the pedal platform, which could address your issue.

#### Is this even a problem?

If you are not currently experiencing problems (i.e., discomfort or pain), then arguably this is not an issue.  Not having your full foot supported could however cause discomfort on longer rides if you use soft shoes, as your foot will be bending around the pedal platform. This would be less of an issue with cycling specific footwear, which have stiff soles to better support the foot.

Answer (score 3):

Where your toes are falling isn't of consequence and will be very different with various pedals. Conventional wisdom is you want the ball of your foot, the bony part forward of your arch and behind your big toe, to be bearing all the load, so that none is borne by tendons, muscles, etc. Typically how it feels is the final determinant of whether you have it right or not.